# ## operator in C does not paste as expected

Tags: c, macros, token

```
struct ms {
        uint64_t a;
        uint64_t b;
        uint64_t c;
        uint64_t d;
};
#define MS_INC(ms, name) ms->##name++

...
struct ms m;
MS_INC(&m, a);
```

It is giving me error: "pasting "a" and "++" does not give a valid preprocessing token"

Is it not allowed to paste `->' or '.' ?

Comment: Hm. Why `##`? `#define MS_INC(ms, name) ms->name++` works just fine. `->` is a separate token.

Comment: The `##` should result in a single preprocessor token. But pasting `.` or `->` will result in at least two.

Comment: You only need to use `##` if you need to combine two tokens into one. If you have `#define prefix uint` and `#define suffix 64`, you might use `prefix ## suffix ## _t` to create `uint64_t`

Answer (score 2):

> It is giving me error: "pasting "a" and "++" does not give a valid preprocessing token"

And it is right.  And C does not allow the token-pasting operator to be used like that.

It looks like you want to produce an expression of the form

```
ms->name++
```

Note well that that is composed of *four* tokens: `ms`, `->`, `name`, and `++`.  If your token-pasting operation were performed where the macro argument corresponding to `name` in fact had the form of an identifier, say `Mark`, then the result would be a single token `->Mark` (between two others).  `->Mark` is not a valid token.

Although whitespace often does separate tokens, it is not required between most tokens.  On the other hand, it is always *allowed* between tokens, so you could always write the above expression like this, instead:

```
ms -> name ++
```

or like this:

```
ms->name ++
```

or like this:

```
ms /* look, Ma, a comment! */
    ->name
  ++
```

As far as I can tell, your macro has absolutely no need for token pasting. Just remove the `##`.